# pandas if then statement without looping

Tags: python, if-statement, pandas, dataframe

All I'm trying to do is add columns `data1` and `data2` if in the same row `letters` is `a` and subtract if it is `c`. multipy if it is `b`. Here is my code.

```
import pandas as pd

a=[['Date', 'letters', 'data1', 'data2'], ['1/2/2014', 'a', 6, 1], ['1/2/2014', 'a', 3, 1], ['1/3/2014', 'c', 1, 3],['1/3/2014', 'b', 3, 5]]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(a[1:],columns=a[0])

df['result']=df['data1']
for i in range(0,len(df)):
    if df['letters'][i]=='a':
        df['result'][i]=df['data1'][i]+df['data2'][i]
    if df['letters'][i]=='b':
        df['result'][i]=df['data1'][i]*df['data2'][i]
    if df['letters'][i]=='c':
        df['result'][i]=df['data1'][i]-df['data2'][i]

>>> df
       Date letters  data1  data2  result
0  1/2/2014       a      6      1       7
1  1/2/2014       a      3      1       4
2  1/3/2014       c      1      3      -2
3  1/3/2014       b      3      5      15
```

My question: is there a way to do it in one line without looping? something to the spirit of:

```
df['result']=df['result'].map(lambda x:df['data1'][i]+df['data2'][i] if x =='a' df['data1'][i]-df['data2'][i] elif x =='c' else x)`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`df.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) in combination with a lambda function. You have to use the keyword argument `axis=1` to ensure you work on rows as opposed to the columns.

```
import pandas as pd

a=[['Date', 'letters', 'data1', 'data2'], ['1/2/2014', 'a', 6, 1], ['1/2/2014', 'a', 3, 1], ['1/3/2014', 'c', 1, 3]]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(a[1:],columns=a[0])

from operator import add, sub, mul

d = dict(a=add, b=mul, c=sub)

df['result'] = df.apply(lambda r: d[r['letters']](r['data1'], r['data2']), axis=1)
```

This will use the dictionary `d` to get the function you wish to use (`add`, `sub`, or `mul`).

**Original solution below**

```
df['result'] = df.apply(lambda r: r['data1'] + r['data2'] if r['letters'] == 'a' 
                        else r['data1'] - r['data2'] if r['letters'] == 'c' 
                        else r['data1'] * r['data2'], axis=1)

print(df)
       Date letters  data1  data2  result
0  1/2/2014       a      6      1       7
1  1/2/2014       b      3      1       3
2  1/3/2014       c      1      3      -2
```

The lambda function is a bit complex now so I'll go into it in a bit more detail...

The lambda function uses a so-called ternary operator to make boolean conditions inside one line, a typical ternary expession is of the form

```
a if b else c
```

Unfortunately you can't have an `elif` with a ternary expression, but what you can do is place another one inside the `else` statement, then it becomes

```
a if b else c if d else e
```

Comment: Can you throw an `elif` and `else` in there too? I just tried this `df['result']=df.apply(lambda x:  x['data1']+x['data2'] if x['letters'] =='a' x['data1']-x['data2'] elif x['letters'] =='c' else x)` and getting a syntax error. I've moved the `elif` around to different places but can't get it to work

Comment: I need to use the `elif` because I actually have more than 2 conditions

Comment: I also tried this `df['result']=df.apply(lambda x:  x['data1']+x['data2'] if x['letters'] =='a' else x['data1']-x['data2'] if x['letters'] =='c' else x)`

Comment: I've copied your code. getting a syntax error. the arrow is pointing to the comma before `axis=1`

Comment: Wow. thanks. Your alternative solutions looks cool. But I'm not sure how readable it will be once I do more than just simple add and subtract. But I will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.where` method:

```
where(cond, other=nan, inplace=False, axis=None, level=None, try_cast=False, raise_on_error=True) method of pandas.core.series.Series instance
```

> Return an object of same shape as self and whose corresponding entries are from self where cond is True and otherwise are from other.

as in:

```
>>> df['data1'] + df['data2'].where(df['letters'] == 'a', - df['data2'])
0    7
1    4
2   -2
dtype: int64
```

alternatively, [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
>>> df['data1'] + np.where(df['letters'] == 'a', 1, -1) * df['data2']
0    7
1    4
2   -2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm going to go with Ffisegydd. It seems more readable to me, also the else if is important to me.